# static const variable as macro

Tags: c++, constants, static-variables

I'm programming in C++ and want to use static const variables instead of macros for magic values. In the example:

```
static const int myx = 10;

int incbyx(int y){
    return y + myx;
}
```

The assembly generated directly uses the value 10:

```
103ec8: e283300a    add r3, r3, #10
```

However I see the variable still occupies space in memory. I came to this conclusion by using objdump with --syms option:

```
001059a8 l     O .data  00000004 myx
```

I don't see the need for this, since the variable itself is never referenced. Can I instruct the compiler/linker not to save space in the data section for it? Or do you have any other suggestion not involving macros?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Debug or release build and if release what optimisation level?  If debug build why do you expect this optimisation to happen?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! And yeah I was both compiling with debug and -O0. Removed debug flag, and with O2 and the problem completely went away! Sorry for the noob question!

Answer (score 1):

If you take `myx`'s address, then it must exist. If you don't, the compiler is free to elide it.

Any good compiler with optimisations switched on will do this.

Answer (score 0):

If optimizations are enabled the codes generated with macro and constant are the same, see [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/wMycjj).